# Bessel J function of complex argument in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using [gnuplot](/questions/tagged/gnuplot) for plotting most of my data and functions. Now, I want to plot Bessel J functions of the zeroeth and first kind, with a complex argument.

The functions `besj0` and `besj1` are implemented in gnuplot. However, according to the user manual only for real (or integer) arguments. I want to use a complex number as an argument, e.g.

```
gnuplot> plot(besj0({0,1}*x))  
         can only do bessel functions of reals
```

How can I circumvent this issue, and use complex arguments for these Bessel J functions?

Comment: You can use e.g. octave to generate a data file which you then plot with gnuplot: `x = linspace(0,10); j = besselj(0, 1i*x);`. BTW: The current development version contains the functionality to load functions from external libraries. Maybe that feature will make it into version 5 :)

Comment: @Christoph Yes, but this is not really the solution I am looking for, especially, since `x` does not per se have zero real part. For now, I think I solved it with a Taylor series, but I am not sure if that is completely correct.

Comment: I know that it isn't a solution ;) The example with the imaginary `x` was only to show the principle. I don't think you can expand the Bessel function as Taylor series, because the part for imaginary `x` grows exponentially. For a related? question see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/458984

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for your link. Well, I am interested in `|x|<R` only, so I think it might work, by just copying enough terms from Maple, or something like that.

Comment: Or you do something like `plot '< echo "x = linspace(0,1); y = besselj(0, (1+1i)*x); dlmwrite(stdout, [x; real(y); imag(y)]'', ''\t'');" | octave -q' u 1:2, "" u 1:3` :)

Comment: @Christoph If I take the Taylor series up to `x^24` or the zeroth Bessel J function, the deviation is smaller than 1% for y<15, so I am probably fine for my application. Your solution probably works probably, only, I have Matlab installed, not Octave :)

Comment: For matlab I couldn't find a one liner to write to stdout. However, this works with matlab: `system('matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r "x = linspace(0,1); y = besselj(0, (1+1i)*x); dlmwrite(''output.txt'', [x; real(y); imag(y)]'', ''\t''); exit;"'); plot "output.txt" u 1:2, "" u 1:3`

Comment: @Christoph Thanks. I am a bit afraid for the system load, because I am actually using it in a loop inside gnuplot. I think I'll stick with my series expansion for now.

Comment: Sure, just wanted to show the working principle with matlab.

Comment: you can't shove a complex argument into a bessel function built for real arguments.  if you get any result at all, it will be wrong.  it should if it receives a complex argument refuse and exit.