# von Mises distribution with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, bessel-functions

I need to fit some data to the von Mises distribution:
[image]

but before to do that I would like to plot this function first in gnuplot. I want to reproduce the curves for different k values, you can see them in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution.

My problem relies on the term Io(k) which is the  modified Bessel function of order 0.
Io(k)=Jo(ik), where Jo is the bessel function for n=0, basically from this equation:[image].

In gnuplot one can plot Jo(k) with the function

```
> besj0(k)
```

but I cannot:

```
besj0(i*k) when the argument is imaginary.
```

Does anybody have an idea how to plot the von Mises distribution in gnuplot?

Comment: @andyras, do you have any suggestion?:)

Comment: This is essentially the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506609/bessel-j-function-of-complex-argument-in-gnuplot), which unfortunately doesn't have a complete answer. The answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/851732/how-to-use-mathematical-functions-not-built-in-in-gnuplot) has a potential workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the development version of Gnuplot, which currently [supports](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/gnuplot-main/ci/master/tree/NEWS) modified Bessel functions of the first kind. Specifically, `I0` is available as `besi0`.